# How to convert this CURL command into PHP code

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to translate this CURL command that is needed to communicate to a web-service.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/gpx+xml' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary @/home/x/gpslog.gpx "http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/?app_id=YOUR_APPID&app_key=YOUR_APPKEY" -o output.json
```

I have my own APPID and APPKEY that I substitute them in the command and also in php code. My gpx logs (xml files) are in /home/x folder that I want to send them to web-service.

I wrote this code but it seems doesn't work (in $params I've set some arguments that needed for me.):

```
$url = 'http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$filePath= '/home/x/gpslog.gpx';
$fields = array('file' => new CurlFile($filePath));

$params = array('app_id' => 'MY-APP-ID', 'app_key' => 'MY-APP-KEY', 'output.groupByWays' => 'false', 'output.linkGeometries' => 'false','output.osmProjection' => 'false','output.linkMatchingError' => 'false','output.waypoints' => 'true','output.waypointsIds' => 'true');
$url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
curl_close($resource);
```

I think the problem may arise because of "Content-Type: application/gpx+xml" that I don't know how to write it in php and also other options of the main CURL command.

After executing this piece of code the result is empty and no errors or warnings are produced.